# How does the kernel sends information generated by an interrupt to the right process?

Tags: operating-systems, kernel-functions

Andrew S. Tanenbaum, in his book Modern Operating Systems states that,

> When a hardware interrupt occurs while a user thread is running, the interrupted CPU switches into kernel mode. If the interrupt is caused by an event not of
> interest to the interrupted process, such as completion of another process’ I/O,
> when the interrupt handler has finished, it puts the interrupted thread back in the
> state it was in before the interrupt. If, however, the process is interested in the interrupt, such as the arrival of a page needed by one of the process’ threads, the interrupted thread is not restarted. Instead, it is suspended, and the run-time system is
> started on that virtual CPU, with the state of the interrupted thread on the stack. It
> is then up to the run-time system to decide which thread to schedule on that CPU:
> the interrupted one, the newly ready one, or some third choice.

If the hardware interrupt is caused by the completion of another process' I/O and the interrupted thread is put back in the original state won't it lead to loss of information required by the process for which the interrupt was meant to be?

Comment: The information transfer is always DMA. The information is somewhere in uncached and unswappable RAM. No loss of information there.

Comment: The kernel keeps a structure of which DMA operation belongs to which thread. During an interrupt, the IO device will write some data in RAM to tell which operation is finished and which isn't.

Comment: The thread state does not include the contents of memory